# How to find the right year in this DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
#df
timeperiod GDP
2000q1     20
2000q2     19
2000q3     18
2000q4     17
2001q1     16
2001q2     17
2001q3     18
2001q4     19
```

A recession is defined as starting with two consecutive quarters of GDP decline, and ending with two consecutive quarters of GDP growth.

English is my second language...So the first thing that confused me is that in my little example, 2000q3 is the start of recession right? Or should the start be 2000q4?

Back to the code problem, I have tried to use a loop to find the start year of recession but I failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

#Data Creation
timePeriod = ['2000q1','2000q2','2000q3','2000q4','2001q1','2001q2','2001q3','2001q4']
GDP = [20,19,18,17,16,17,18,19]
data = zip(timePeriod,GDP)
data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['timePeriod','GDP'])
print(data)

#Track beginning of recession
counter = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if(counter!=2):
        if(data['GDP'][i]> data['GDP'][i+1]):
            counter= counter+1
    else:
        print('Recession Started:'+data['timePeriod'][i])
        break
```

**After adding second condition:**

```
counter = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
     if(counter!=2):
         if(data['GDP'][i]> data['GDP'][i+1]):
             counter= counter+1
     elif(counter==2):    
         print('Recession Started:'+data['timePeriod'][i])    
         if(data['GDP'][i]< data['GDP'][i+1]):  
             print("Recession Ended:"+data['timePeriod'][i])   
             break
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I try to find the end year using this method, but it keeps giving back about "Key Error:1'

Comment: You can add one more condition where you can check, if GDP is increasing.